# Getting pyglet errors when importing joystick in PsychoPy

Tags: psychopy

I'm trying to use the joystick in PsychoPy and I can't import the module without getting the following error:

```
File "joytest.py", line 1, in <module>
  from psychopy.hardware import joystick
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/joystick/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  import pyglet_input
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/joystick/pyglet_input/__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
  from x11_xinput import get_devices as xinput_get_devices
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/psychopy/hardware/joystick/pyglet_input/x11_xinput.py", line 11, in <module>
  from pyglet.input.base import \
ImportError: No module named input.base
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, running Python 2.7.6, PsychoPy 1.79.01, and pyglet 1.1.4. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's a relatively ancient release of PsychoPy (Dec 2013), so not sure how much useful help you'll get here on dependency issues.

Comment: Try installing a newer psychopy. Version 1.82.02 is in the neuro.debian repository for Ubuntu 14.04 and will update with new releases. If you don't have it already, take a look at http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=psychopy

Comment: Updating PsychoPy didn't solve the problem, but updating pyglet did. Apparently the input.base module was added in pyglet 1.2.